# Redirect Manager 301 results in "Entry DNE" error

Tags: plugins, redirect, redirection

This is my old URL. No entry exists here:

```
/post/234234234234/happy-fourth-of-july
```

This entry exists:

```
/news/happy-fourth-of-july
```

I have the Redirect Manager plugin setup as follows:
[image: Redirect Manager Configuration]

However when I visit the old URL (above) the URL remains unchanged and I receive a `Variable "entry" does not exist` template error.

I must be missing something really obvious, so if I can provide more infomation, let me know.

Comment: Redirect Manager is good, but I like [Retour](https://github.com/nystudio107/retour/) even better. It'll automatically detect if your entry path changes, and create a matching redirect accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Lindsey. I checked out Retour but I was turned off because of the number of files contained within the plugin. Seemed overkill for something so simple. I'll revisit if I can't figure something out soon though.

For a single redirect I could probably create an .htaccess entry, but I wasn't having much success there either.

Comment: Not sure if "number of files" is the right metric. If you really want to minimize the number of files here, you'd do this with an `.htaccess` file, or at the [system level](https://nystudio107.com/blog/stop-using-htaccess-files-no-really). Coincidentally (or not), that article is actually written by the author of Retour.

Comment: I've just had a shot at installing and configuring Retour, but I'm winding up with the same error as previously. This probably confirms that the problem is user error and not the plugins, but either way I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that I was right on the money with my plugin configurations, however earlier I had incorrectly tried to solve the problem using the route below, which was still in place and scuppering my subsequent good work!

[image]